# How to run a startup script for every notebook in datalab?

Tags: python, jupyter, google-cloud-datalab

When using `Jupyter`, I can add python files in the `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup` folder and those files will be ran as a startup script on every notebook I create/open. This is useful so I don't have to import all variables and configurations every time. (e.g, i can do `from mymodels import *` or `my_db.configure(production.ini)`)

Is there a similar feature in Datalab?

Note that I'm not referring to the startup.sh script in `/content/datalab/.config/startup.sh`, which runs scripts prior to the notebook daemon.